# Syntax for me to input values in Go Language

Tags: go

I've been looking for a way how to have a syntax like this in C

```
scanf("%d",&num);
```

and I've found out in Go Lanuguage you can use this

```
fmt.scanf("%d",&num)
```

The problem is when I'll use it twice, it doesn't allow me to enter a value on the second part.

Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var name string
    var age int
    fmt.Print("Enter your name: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &name)
    fmt.Print("\nEnter your age: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &age)
    fmt.Println(name,"is",age,"years of Age")
}
```

Sample input name=Jack and age=18(this is the part of the problem wherein it doesn't allow me to input for the age)
it will display

```
Jack is 0 years of age
```

Comment: You're ignoring the return values of `Scanf`, so checking those would be the first thing to do when debugging the problem.

Comment: Are you using an input file? Try to do it without it, using the keyboard instead, just "go run xxx.go" and then insert Jack (return) 18 (return). It works for me in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the last line with this:

```
fmt.Printf("%s is %d years of age", name, age)
```

Here is the full code:

```
package main                                                                                                                            

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var name string
    var age int 
    fmt.Print("Enter your name: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &name)
    fmt.Print("Enter your age: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &age)
    fmt.Printf("\n%s is %d years of age \n", name, age)
}
```

Output :

> Enter your name: rex
>
> Enter your age: 33
>
> rex is 33 years of age

Comment: It still doesn't work...the problem was that it doesn't allow me to input in the second part "Enter your age" it just proceed directly to "rex is 0 years of age"

Comment: @shadowj3yz you sure?  I put my code above in main.go then ran "go run main.go" and I was asked for the second part (age). the output I indicated in my answer is the actual output I got running the code.

Comment: @shadowj3yz Are you running it in the Go Playground? Stdin doesn't work there, try running it locally.

Comment: I'm using the Go Programming Language in windows via command promt

Comment: @shadowj3yz I don't think working on windows vs linux would matter in this case. Copy and pasting my code did not give you the desired results?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
"bufio"
"fmt"
"os"
"strings"
)

func main() {

r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("Enter your name: ")
name, _ := r.ReadString('\n')

fmt.Print("Enter your age: ")
age, _ := r.ReadString('\n')
name, age = strings.TrimSpace(name), strings.TrimSpace(age) //remove \n
fmt.Println(name, "is", age, "years of Age")

}
```